# Why one line only is inserted?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use 3 tables to insert data for a 4th table.
My tables :

```
Typology
id_typo------PK
name_typology----

Country
id_country---PK
name_country---

Brut
id_brut------PK
name_typology--
name_country---

Structure
id_struct---PK
id_typo-----fk
id_country---fk
```

I want transfert the data from the table Brut to the table Structure.
The problem is that one line is inserted. Why ?

My request :

```
INSERT INTO structure (id_struct,id_typo,id_country) 
SELECT x.id_struct,y.id_typo, z.id_country,
FROM brut AS x, typology AS y, country AS z 
WHERE x.name_typology = y.name_typology AND x.name_country = z.name_country
```

Comment: What is the data? Does every row on the brut table have matching rows on BOTH the typology and country tables?

Comment: Thks for answer. Yes, that's right.

Comment: What happens if you execute just the SELECT part?

Comment: Can you post some example data that demonstrates the problem. Other than an extra comma in the SELECT (which would cause an error and no rows inserted) there is nothing I can see that would cause only a single row to be inserted beyond an issue with the data.

Comment: `SELECT ..., FROM ...` There is a stray comma there. Pretty sure that will cause problems. You should use parentheses or indentation to indicate sub queries.

Comment: Without example data it is impossible to diagnose the cause of your problem; we'll just be guessing.  You should create a simplified data-set and attempt to replicate your problem with that.  On its own that will likely assist you in solving your own problem.  If it doesn't then it also lets you copy and paste that simplified data set in to your question so that we can replicate it in something like sqlfiddle.  In short, reading this following link will help you help yourself, and help you help us; http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join if you dont have matching rows in table y & z so that atleast you get all rows from table x:

```
    INSERT INTO structure (id_struct,id_typo,id_country) 
    SELECT x.id_struct,y.id_typo, z.id_country,
    FROM brut AS x 
    left join typology AS y on trim(x.name_typology) = trim(y.name_typology)
    left join country AS z on trim(x.name_country) = trim(z.name_country)
```

Comment: there is also a construct called `Select INTO` you could use, here u have a url: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Answer (score 0):

May be issue about space to name
Use this query to remove space

```
INSERT INTO structure (id_struct,id_typo,id_country) 
SELECT x.id_struct,y.id_typo, z.id_country,
FROM brut AS x, typology AS y, country AS z 
WHERE trim(x.name_typology) = trim(y.name_typology) AND trim(x.name_country) = trim(z.name_country)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. All problems are resolved. 
I put the LEFT JOIN :

```
INSERT INTO structure (id_struct,id_typo,id_country)  
SELECT x.id_struct,y.id_typo, z.id_country,
FROM brut as x
LEFT JOIN typology as y
ON x.name_typology = y.name_typology
LEFT JOIN country as z 
ON x.name_country = z.name_country
```

And I have all lines inserted :-)

Comment: Great!! Nice to hear that.